Как поднять проект из нескольких пакетов с setuptools
В наследство достался проект, включающий в себя несколько пакетов, собирающихся через setuptools. Структура проекта следующая:
server/
  ├── requirements.txt
  ├── pkg1/
       ├── pkg1/
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── main.py
            └── ...  
       └── setup.py          
  ├── pkg2/  
       ├── pkg2/
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── main.py
            └── ...  
       └── setup.py             
  └── ...

Некоторые пакеты зависят только от внешних библиотек из requirements.txt, некоторые только от соседних модулей (напр. pkg1 имеет в зависимостях только pkg2), некоторые и от соседей и от внешних.
Пример файла setup.py:
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


def get_version():
  return os.environ.get("PEP440_VERSION", "0.0.0.1")


setup(
  name="pkg1",
  version=get_version(),
  packages=find_packages(),
  entry_points={
    "console_scripts": ["pkg1 = module.main:main"],
  },
  install_requires=["pkg2"],
  ...
)

Вопрос, как это чудо поднять?
На текущий момент пришел к тому, что:

сделал общее виртуальное окружение в папке server
в этой же папке запустил pip install -r requirements.txt
в каждой директории (pkg1, pkg2, ...) запустил pip install --editable .

Далее из папки server запускаю команду python pkg1/src/main.py. Результат ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg2.util'
Проект успешно запускается через docker-compose, но в моем случае нужно это запустить нативно через python.
Любая помощь приветствуется!

Логичный вопрос - этот самый pkg2.util вообще существует?

Хотя вообще меня очень смущает структура проекта: если всё хранится в pkg2/src/ и setup.py содержит тупое find_packages() без уточнений, то вроде получается, что src это подмодуль и нужно импортировать pkg2.src.util. Как вся эта дребедень может работать в docker-compose - для меня немножко загадка в таком случае, может докерфайлы меняют структуру проекта при копировании в контейнер?

Или даже не так: поскольку setup.py и src находятся на одном уровне, значит src это получается модуль верхнего уровня и импортировать нужно src.util без всяких там pkg2. Но тогда получается, что модуль src предоставляется сразу двумя пакетами pkg1 и pkg2 и они обязаны конфликтовать друг с другом - в общем весело там у вас  Наверно, докерфайлы как-то разруливают всю эту дичь

@andreymal да, в докерфайлах много магии, пока ее не успели всю разобрать. pkg2.util  существует, это лишь пример, таких импортов много по проекту. К сожалению, я уже не уверен, что проект собирался нативно без докера, но меня информировали, что это возможно. Документации и связи с предыдущими разработчиками нет, к сожалению, чтобы выяснить подробности

@andreymal поправил структуру, переименовал директорию src т.к. фактически она имеет название такое же как и директория подмодуля. Возможно это даст какие-то мысли?

Ну тогда всё логично и красиво, и вопрос из первого комментария снова становится актуален

А хотя на самом деле не совсем — питон всё равно может пытаться импортировать наружний pkg2 вместо внутреннего, из чего следует, что вместо pkg2.util существует pkg2.pkg2.util. Самым очевидным решением в таком случае будет тупая смена текущего каталога на какой-нибудь другой вместо каталога server

Если прописать путь импорта как from server.pkg2.pkg2.util import ... то ошибка ModuleNotFoundError для этого импорта уже не падает. Но модули получается поднимали без начального server.pkg2....

Хотя вообще воспроизвести проблему «в лоб» у меня не получается — Python вроде как не смотрит текущий каталог при импортах, если не запускать командный интерпретатор и если не вмешаться вручную в sys.path. Этот вот main.py случайно не модифицирует sys.path добавляя в него текущий каталог например?
